# having a master database for a django project

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a small team of 5 and I need help finding resources or advice on how to have one centralized MySQL database. We all work virtual and host all the files on one github to centralize everything. So it would be a pain to have 5 local databases on different computers all with the same information as we work scripting logic from the models and etc that will be the same.

**The github_cm_dev:** is the main directory inside gitHub

**venv:** is the virtual environment (so anyone on the team can use and activate the environment easily)

**indieitude-project/indieitude directory:** Has all of my django applications and files

**indieitude-project/indieitude/indieitude directory:** has all the config files i.e. settings, urls.p etc

Any advice or thoughts on the matter?

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally there is one master database -- the production DB. There are three general options here:

1) If the data isn't too sensitive and a dev doesn't need every last change, you can simply let each dev take a dump file from production and apply it to their machine.

2) If the data is sensitive (e.g. w/ user passwords), you can create a "dummy" version of the DB and use that as the canonical data for local dev and for testing.

3) If you need every change on each user's machine, then you can preload the entries you need with django fixture files. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/  You can create a fixture file from a DB pretty easily. A fixture file is just text so you can put it in your  git repo.

Comment: So how would I go about implementing option #2? since we will have some sensitive data

Comment: @Amechi, you either build it up from scratch, or subtract sensitive stuff from the prod DB.  For the latter, do a `manage.py dumpdata` to get the data into a text file, and manually remove the sensitive stuff.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dumpdata